# want to change the text for different label with one for c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to do a logo quiz game . and i did this code for now

```
int a=0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
    a = 1;

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button2.BackgroundImage;
    a = 2;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button3.BackgroundImage;
    a = 3;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button4.BackgroundImage;
    a = 4;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button5.BackgroundImage;
    a = 5;
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button6.BackgroundImage;
    a = 6;
}

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button7.BackgroundImage;
    a = 7;
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button8.BackgroundImage;
    a = 8;
}

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button9.BackgroundImage;
    a = 9;
}

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button10.BackgroundImage;
    a = 10;
}

private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button11.BackgroundImage;
    a = 11;
}

private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button12.BackgroundImage;
    a = 12;
}

private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button13.BackgroundImage;
    a = 13;
}

private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button14.BackgroundImage;
    a = 14;
}

private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button15.BackgroundImage;
    a = 15;
}

private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = button16.BackgroundImage;
    a = 16;
}

private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    int scor = 0;

    List<string> numeLogo = new List<string>(); // audi,bentley,cadillac,chevrolet,dodge,alfa romeo
    numeLogo.Add("audi");                       // ferrari,peugeot,volkswagen,trabant,mitsubishi,mazda
    numeLogo.Add("bentley");                       // opel,maserati,lamborghini,mercedes
    numeLogo.Add("cadillac");
    numeLogo.Add("chevrolet");
    numeLogo.Add("dodge");
    numeLogo.Add("alfa romeo");
    numeLogo.Add("ferrari");
    numeLogo.Add("peugeot");
    numeLogo.Add("volkswagen");
    numeLogo.Add("trabant");
    numeLogo.Add("mitsubishi");
    numeLogo.Add("mazda");
    numeLogo.Add("opel");
    numeLogo.Add("maserati");
    numeLogo.Add("lamborghini");
    numeLogo.Add("mercedes");





    for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
    {
        if (a == i)
            if (textBox1.Text == numeLogo[i - 1])
            {

                MessageBox.Show("bravo");


            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("nu e bine");
    }



}
```

under each button i have a label . if the player guesses the logo , under the button the label.text must change.

i don't know how to do this with a for.

i can do something like `for(i=1; i<=n; i++){ label[i].Text == "x" }`  ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should move you question logic into a new class or classes. 

You may also want to take a look add some of this logic in Winform Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, just declare your label array:

```
private List<Label> Labels { 
get { 
   return new List<Label>() {label1, label2, label3}; } 
}
```